# CSS: Position sticky getting scrolled

Tags: css

Please visit this page in a mobile view in the browser and inspect - [page](https://prod.novanthealth.org/Assets/Storybook/iframe.html?id=pages-clinic-pages-clinic-interior-page--clinic-interior-page&args=&viewMode=story).

[image]

I need to set the header (`div` with classes `ClinicHeaderMobile-module__header--ycbjx default default`) as position `sticky` which is currently set to `fixed`. The reason is there would be a of case dynamic `div` for alert being added sometimes above the header (which would have a `static` position taking space for its own height and width), so the header needs to shift down to accommodate the alert `div` height.

Now, even when I change the header `div` position to `sticky` in dev tools, I see it is being scrolled on scrolling the page and not keeping it sticky.

[image]

On inspecting further, I see there is a 3rd nested `div` in the header for the hamburger menu with classes `nav-bars slide-out` which has style `transform: translateX(100%)` for a couple of rules - `.ClinicHeaderMobile-module__header--ycbjx .nav-bars.slide-out` and `.ClinicHeaderMobile-module__header--ycbjx .nav-bars`. When I uncheck the transform property from both these rules, the header seems to working as sticky upon scrolling. I am not sure why the `transform` property in the nested `div` is causing the header not to behave as sticky even with position `sticky` and how to fix it.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question as text in a [mre].

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it as a minimal example, so had to put the link to the web page directly